# Get Drawable id for dynamically generated Resource Name/String

Tags: java, android, performance

the .setBackgroundResource can only accept an int and not a string, but it would look much nicer if it wouldnt be so fat and ugly for every 'levelup' for fabrik, so is there a way to simplify this:

```
    datafab1 = getSharedPreferences("datafab1", MODE_PRIVATE);

 if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 3) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl3);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 4) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl4);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 5) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl5);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 6) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl6);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 7) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl7);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 8) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl8);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 9) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl9);
        }
        if (datafab1.getInt("Level", 1) == 10) {
            Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fablvl10);
        }
```

to something like this:

```
    datafab1 = getSharedPreferences("datafab1", MODE_PRIVATE);

String fablvl1nr = "R.drawable.fablvl"+Integer.toString(datafab1.getInt("Level", 1));
    Fabrik1.setBackgroundResource(fablvl1nr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `getIdentifier` of the Resource class:

```
int i = datafab1.getInt("Level", 1);
int id= getResources().getIdentifier("fablvl"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks @daemmie. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please consider to upvote it!

Comment: @EmanuelGraf I already did. long time ago.... So you probably have a downvote on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier("fablvl"+datafab1.getInt("Level", 1), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks @ManishJain. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please consider to upvote it!